# Subtracting signed binary numbers without two's complement

Tags: c, binary, arbitrary-precision

So I'm trying to write code to subtract two binary numbers but I'm not sure how to tackle this problem elegantly. The structures that hold the binary numbers are as follows.

```
typedef struct _bitb {
    short bit;
    struct _bitb *nbit;
} BitB;
typedef struct _bignum {
    short sign;
    BitB *bits;
} BigNum;
```

Thus a binary number is represented by a list of bits containing its absolute value, from the LSB to the MSB, and then a short that says whether the number is positive or negative (it's an implementation of arbitrary precision arithmetic). How can I subtract one number from the other without two's complement?

And before someone asks, this is for school, but I don't want a solution in code, just a general algorithm that I can implement. I've been searching around and it seems like there isn't a good algorithm that can solve the general case. Do I need to check the signs of the numbers and then implement code for all the possible cases (negative minus positive, positive minus negative, positive minus positive, negative minus positive)? Or should I just convert to 2's complement?

Comment: You can traverse the two lists parallely and process bit by bit. You can have a truth table for subtraction which outputs 2 bits (the difference and borrow). At every step you will get a difference bit and a borrow. The difference bit can be stored in a third linked list (the result) and the borrow can be used in the next iteration.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think that works but only when subtracting a positive number from a positive one, am I not correct?

Comment: Different operations between signed numbers are essentially additions or subtractions. Addition you already know how to do, subtraction like I said. You just have to calculate the appropriate sign and append it.

Comment: You will need 2's complemement in the case of `A-B` where `|A| < |B|`. e.g. if `A = 2`and `B = 5`, `A-B` will be `-3` You will have to take the 2's complement of the result. `-(5-3)` So not sure how you can avoid 2's complement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the problem to two cases: opposite signs and same signs.

Subtracting numbers that have opposite signs requires adding the two absolute values. Examples:

```
(-7) - (+5) = -(7+5)
(+7) - (-5) = +(7+5)
```

To subtract numbers that have the same sign, you need to subtract the smaller absolute value from the larger absolute value. Examples:

```
(+7) - (+5) = +(7-5)
(+7) - (+9) = -(9-7)
(-7) - (-5) = -(7-5)
(-7) - (-9) = +(9-7)
```

And as you can see there are actually six cases for the sign of the result, as shown below (where X, Y and Z are the magnitude of the number).

```
(-X) - (+Y) ==> -(Z)
(+X) - (-Y) ==> +(Z)
(+X) - (+Y) and (X >= Y) ==> +(Z)
(+X) - (+Y) and (X <  Y) ==> -(Z)
(-X) - (-Y) and (X >  Y) ==> -(Z)
(-X) - (-Y) and (X <= Y) ==> +(Z)
```

In summary:

If the two numbers have opposite signs, then add the magnitudes.
If the two numbers have the same sign, then subtract the smaller magnitude from the larger magnitude.
Then determine the sign of the result.

Answer (score 4):

> this is for school, but I don't want a solution in code, just a general algorithm that I can implement

`BigNum` is a sign-magnitude linked list encoding of an integer.

To add/subtract `BigNum`, code needs to be made to add/subtract the magnitude of each `BitB` operand.

To add magnitude, it is simple enough to walk the `BitB` linked lists and form the sum as you go.

```
// pseudo-code
BitB *BitBAdd(const BitB *a, const BitB *b) {
  BitB temp_head = set next member to NULL
  BitB *bit_walker = pointer to the head
  bool carry = false;
  while (a is not end of list, b not end of list, or carry) {
    bool abit = get bit from a if not NULL and advance a, else 0
    bool bbit = get bit from b if not NULL and advance b, else 0
    bit_walker->nbit =  malloc(sizeof *(bit_walker->nbit));
    check allocation success
    advance bit_walker
    set bit_walker->nbit members to NULL, abit ^ bbit ^ carry
    carry = majority(abit, bbit, carry);
  }
  return temp_head.nbit;
}
```

The subtraction of magnitude entails finding the larger one first: `int BitBCmp(const BitB *a, const BitB *b)`. Code not shown.  The subtraction function `BitB *BitBCmp(const BitB *larger, const BitB *smaller)` is then similar to `BitBAdd()`.  Not shown.

Once `BitBAdd()`, `BitBCmp()` and `BitBSub()` are made, then `BigNum_Add()` and `BigNum_Sub()` can be made by examining the signs and calling various `BitB...()` as suggested by [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959526/2410359).

---

Side issues

`BitBAdd()` represents about 20-25% of the code needed to fulfill OP's task.

Lopping off of most-significant zero digits may be desired.  Also consider sign-magnitude encodings could generate +0 and -0.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2's complemement in the case of `A-B` where `|A| < |B|`. e.g. if `A = 2`and `B = 5`, `A-B` will be `-3` You will have to take the 2's complement of the result. `-(5-3)`. You have to use 2's complement in any case.

I would suggest that you use 2's complement to convert your subtraction into an addition.

i.e. if you have `ans = A-B` take the 2's complement of `B` and then add.

You will then get `ans = A + (-B)`.

Step 1. Take 2's complement of B

Step 2. Add A with the 2's complement.

This will simplify the code to a great extent.

Also, this is how subtraction of numbers is handled inside the CPU.